# When a user click on Login it should redirect to login with google page in react js Can you help me resolve this issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

When a user click on login button it will go to Login page
[image]

Like this [image]

I am creating this website for my portfolio But i am facing an error here is my Login and loginwtihgoogle component

Login component

```
 import React from 'react'

const Login = () => {
  return (
    <>
            <div className='login-icon hover:text-yellow-800'>
                <a href='Loginwithgoogle'>
                <img src="/src/assets/login.png" alt="login icon" className='mt-2 ml-14 h-8 '/>
                <figcaption className='text-white text-center ml-14 text-[9px] hover:text-yellow-800'>LOGIN</figcaption>
                    </a>

             </div>
            
            </>
  )
}

export default Login
```

Here is loginwithgoogle component

```
   import React from 'react'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
const Loginwithgoogle = () => {

    function handleCallBackResponse(response){
        console.log("Encoded JWT  ID Token " + response.credential);
    }
    useEffect(() => {
     google.accounts.id.initialize({
        client_id: "731249793019-qbik3a0k62db0d3k5vd72j98ivkl2hds.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        callback: handleCallBackResponse
     });
     google.accounts.id.renderButton(
        document.getElementById("signInDiv"),
        { theme: "outline", size:"large"}
     )
    }, [])
    
  return (
    <div className="loginwithgoogle">
        <div id="signInDiv">

        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Loginwithgoogle
```

Here it is main.jsx

```
  import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'

import Bar from './components/Bar'
import IconsText from './components/IconsText'

import Searchbar from './components/Searchbar'
import './index.css'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes,Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import Login from './components/Login'


ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
   <Router>
     <Routes>
      <Route path='/loginwithgoogle' element={<Login/>} />
     </Routes>
   </Router>
     <Bar />
    <IconsText />
    <Searchbar/>
    
    
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```

I need to solve this issue when someone clicked on login it should redirect to loginwthgoogle page

Comment: How exactly did you get the screenshots? It doesn't appear you are rendering any other routes ***but*** the `"/loginwithgoogle"`. How did you get to a `"/account/login"` route and component? The code snippets don't match the screenshots so it's unclear what you are referring to specifically. Where is this `Loginwithgoogle` component rendered?

Comment: I have two component login and loginwithgoogle I know the code is messed you can see first image that i created where you will see login. what i want is when i click on Login the page should redirect to Loginwithgoogle . you can see on the post Three component login loginwithgoogle  and main.jsx

Comment: Well, the ***other*** part that doesn't make sense is that the path you say you are trying to link to is the path rendering the `Login` component which looks like the button/link "thing" you are trying to use to get to the route path rendering itself. Is this all part of some browser extension or something? Where is the code for the UI in the screenshots where there's a login button and a `"/account/login"` route and component? And again, where is `Loginwithgoogle` being rendered so you *can* link to it?

Comment: Forget about it "/account/login"  I wanted to do is when user click on Login it should go to login with google page  here is the route    <Routes>
      <Route path='/loginwithgoogle' element={<Login/>} />
     </Routes> that i give in my main.js what i am doing wrong i dont know i just want to render loginwithgoogle when user click on Login button

Comment: Ok, very well. It seems you want the `Loginwithgoogle` component to render on `"/loginwithgoogle"` instead of the `Login` component, so use `<Route path="/loginwithgoogle" element={<Loginwithgoogle />} />` and then render the `Login` component on a different path so it can render a `Link` component targeting `to="/loginwithgoogle"`. Does this make sense?

Comment: I import link object from react router dom but it gives me an error. Let me check again
Can i connect with you on facebook or any other social media platform.

Comment: Unfortunately no, SO is the communication platform. If we continue on here back and forth there should eventually be a suggestion to start a chat. What is the error when you `import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';`?

Comment: its working but all others components are moving to How i can fix this    <Router>
     <Routes>
      <Route path='/loginwithgoogle' element={<Loginwithgoogle/>} />
     </Routes>
   </Router>
     <Bar />
    <IconsText />
    <Searchbar/>

Comment: What other components are moving? Do you mean the `Bar`, `IconsText`, and `Searchbar` components are rendered below the `Loginwithgoogle` component when it's the matching route?

Comment: Yes bro other component are moving too  like Bar IconText Searchbar.What i want is when user click on Login it should render only Loginwithgoogle. Now problem is When i Click login It renders all other components too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render the `Bar`, `IconsText`, and `Searchbar` components on their own route.

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'))
  .render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <Router>
       <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/" 
          element={(
            <>
              <Bar />
              <IconsText />
              <Searchbar />
            </>
          )}
        />
        <Route path='/loginwithgoogle' element={<Login />} />
       </Routes>
      </Router>
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
```

If you want to render these components conditionally with other routes then create a layout route component.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const Layout = () => (
  <>
    <Bar />
    <IconsText />
    <Searchbar />
    <Outlet />
  </>
);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'))
  .render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <Router>
       <Routes>
        <Route element={<Layout />}>
          ... routes with layout ...
        </Route>

        ... routes without layout ...
        <Route path='/loginwithgoogle' element={<Login />} />
       </Routes>
      </Router>
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
```